# Incorrect UP-TO-DATE with gradle copy task

Tags: gradle, build, copy

I have copy task configured like this:

```
tmp = "$project.buildDir/tmp"
tmpClassesDir = "$tmp/WEB-INF/classes"

task copyFiles(type: Copy) {    
    from sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    include '*properties'
    into tmpClassesDir
}
```

After than clean task deletes build directory, if I run `copyFiles` once again it's *UP-TO-DATE*
It works if I add *--rerun-tasks* or set `outputs.dir` to `tmp`, but when `outputs.dir` is set as `tmpClassesDir` gradle says it's *UP-TO-DATE*

Any ideas what causes that strange behavior?

UPDATE: Problem exists only on remote test servers - when running local it's working well - any ideas?

Comment: where are you setting `outputs.dir`?

Comment: in task configuration - line below into `tmpClassesDir`